# DSolve doesn't solve a second order differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to solve an ordinary differential equation:

```
eqn1 = 2*r*y'[r] + r^2*y''[r] == -4*\[Pi]*G*b*r^2 ( Exp[y[r]/a^2] * Erf[(y[r])^(1/2)/a] - ((4*y[r])/(\[Pi]*a^2))^(1/2) * (1 + (2*y[r])/(3*a^2)))
```

Using DSolve:

```
DSolve[{eqn1, y[0] == c, y'[0] == 0}, y[r], r]
```

But when I try to use `DSolve`, Mathematica just repeats the input in the output field and doesn't evaluate anything. I tried `DSolveValue` but Mathematica still won't evaluate it. When I tried using a simpler damped harmonic oscillator equation as my differential equation, `DSolve` was able to solve it. Is `eqn1` just too difficult for Mathematica to solve?

Comment: The LHS of `eqn1` is `2 r Derivative[1][y][r] + r^2 (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r]` and vanishes at `r==0`, but you define initial values at `r==0`. The returned input is a normal behavior of `DSolve`.

Comment: Maple returns no output, dsolving that problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out what happens at `r==0`. I however, tried the boundary conditions `y'[2]==3` and `y[2]==4`, and still no output. I tried solving without the boundary conditions altogether with no output either. Does this mean the equation has no solution or it's just too difficult to find one.

Comment: I wonder if the presence of `Erf` in your equation is too much for DSolve to find an analytical symbolic solution. Do you need a symbolic solution, or could you make do with a numerical one from NDSolve?

Comment: @MarcoB: `Erf[y[r]]` can be eliminated by differentiating, then `DSolve[D[eqn1, r] /. {y[r] -> Log[w[r]], y'[r] -> D[Log[w[r]], r], 
   y''[r] -> D[Log[w[r]], {r, 2}], y'''[r] -> D[Log[w[r]], {r, 3}]}, 
 w[r], r]`  fails too.